# OpenSSH tcl package

Tags: tcl, openssh

I am trying to replace a tcl/Expect script that calls ssh from Windows.  We are upgrading to a 64-bit OS and Expect does not work with 64 bit Windows.  I am trying to run the code found on [this page](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Many+people+who+think+they+need+Expect+do+not+need+Expect) but I cannot get it to recognize the ssh command in the third line.

`set ssh [open "|ssh -tt -q -o {StrictHostKeyChecking no} $user@$host /bin/sh" r+]`

OpenSSH is installed and I can run ssh commands from the windows command line, but I cannot do it from tcl. I am assuming I need to install an OpenSSH package, but I can't find any information on how to do it or where to get it.

Comment: "I cannot get it to recognize the ssh command" -- what specific errors are you seeing?

Comment: The error is 'couldn't execute "ssh": no such file or directory'

Comment: It looks like a PATH problem. What does `puts [auto_execok ssh]` print?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  

`puts [auto_execok ssh]` doesn't return anything.  I also tried specifying the full path in the command `set ssh [open "|C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe -tt -q -o {StrictHostKeyChecking no} $user@$host /bin/sh" r+]` and that returns the same error.
`

Comment: What is the exact error message? I feel there are missing details.

Comment: The full error message reads:


`couldn't execute "ssh": no such file or directory
     while executing
"open "|ssh -tt -q -o {StrictHostKeyChecking no} $user@$host /bin/sh" r+]"
     (file "CheckSSH.tcl" line 3)
     invoked from within
"set ssh [open "|ssh -tt -q -o {StrictHostKeyChecking no} $user@$host /bin/sh" r+]"
     (file "CheckSSH.tcl" line 3) `

Comment: Read http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm#M24 particularly the paragraph starting "When attempting to execute an application..." -- this seems like a simple PATH issue, but I don't have a Windows machine handy for testing.

Comment: I tried copying the ssh.exe file to the same directory as the script and after changing the `ssh` command to `ssh.exe` it worked.  It seems you are correct about it being a path issue.  Any hints on how to solve that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the punctuation here, but something like `set env(PATH) $env(PATH);C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH"` before calling `open "|ssh ..."` ought to work

Comment: Or, preferable, use Windows to add the openssh dir to the system's PATH

Comment: The OpenSSH directory is already in the Windows path.  Not sure why it's not reading it.